# Ubuntu 22.04 freezes when taking a screenshot with Brave (chrome) console open + right-clicking on the refresh button

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, freeze, 22.04, gnome-screenshot

Today I tried to take a screenshot of the little menu that appears when you right-click the refresh button in Brave (Chrome) and perform "Empty cache and Hard Reload" (when the console is open), but only in that case, when the Screenshot Tool of 22.04 comes up, the whole computer froze. I can take a screenshot normally when the console is open, and in every other situation but when this little menu pops up it freezes.

[Chrome's refresh menu when the console is open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6OO2.png)

The only way to resolve it is to CTRL+ALT+F3 and type `killall -9 gnome-session-b`.

I thought it happened when the console was open, but it seems to happen only with this little menu open. Did anybody face issues like this with 22.04?

Thanks in advance!